# Automatically collapsing a detail when opening another in a shieldui grid hierarchy

Tags: gridview, datagrid, shieldui

I have a ShieldUI grid, and I'm using hierarchy to open a detail underneath individual rows. This works well. The only thing I don't like is that when I open the hierarchy then it leaves the other detail panels open.  I'd like it to behave like an accordion---when one is opened the other closes.

Is there a straightforward way to do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The desired functionality can be achieved via custom code. 
For each expansion of a row, you can collapse all others. 
This can be done via the method below:
http://www.shieldui.com/documentation/grid/javascript/api/methods/collapseRow